# Does the Scheduler creates fixed number of workers on each usage of it?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

**The following code runs inside a loop** and I'd like to know whether new workers are created in each iteration, or maybe once the scheduler is defined at class level then it uses a fixed number of workers but assigns to them different IDs.

In the logs, I see that each iteration the printed IDs of the workers are different and I'm wondering if new workers are created each time in addition to the others before, or the others have already been destroyed.

```
 Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(10, 1000, "test"); //defined outside of the loop.

 Integer numbers = Flux.fromIterable(someList)
                .parallel(10)
                .runOn(scheduler)
                .flatMap(i ->  foo(i))
                .sequential()
                .count()
                .block();
```

Comment: This question is not about spring reactor. You should learn java object lifecycle. However the answer: No, because you create a new one bounded elastic scheduler and it doesn't know about other scheduler in the previous cycle.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus I have edited the code. Please see again